# Kong as redirection service

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

Is it possible to configure HTTP redirection rules in KONG (e.g if request matches `^/old-api/(.*)$` pattern then return 301 to `https://other-domain.org/new-api/$1`) without modifying `nginx.conf` templates (i.e. setup such rules using API and some plugin)?

What I am trying to achive is nginx equivalent of `rewrite` directive with `redirect` or `permanent` flag: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I found an even better answer now.

Using the [Serverless function plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/), it is possible to do a proper redirect with a `Location` header. The following Lua code should do that:

```
kong.response.exit(301, 'page moved - redirecting...', {['Location'] = 'https://other-domain.org/' .. kong.request.get_path_with_query():gsub("%/old-api/", "/new-api/")})
```

After that, the response looks like:

```
# curl -i http://original-domain.org/old-api/abc
HTTP/2 301
date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 17:03:04 GMT
location: https://other-domain.org/new-api/abc
content-length: 28
x-kong-response-latency: 7

page moved - redirecting...
```

---

**Original Answer**:

You can use your regular expressions and [capturing groups](https://docs.konghq.com/2.1.x/proxy/#capturing-groups) in the route definition to save the path (or part of it) in a variable:

```
^/old-api/(?<path>.*)$
```

Regrettably, the Response Transformer cannot simply use the `path` variable to create a `Location: https://other-domain.org/new-api/$(uri_captures.<path>)` header, like the [Request Transformer Plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/) can (see https://konghq.com/blog/url-rewriting-in-kong).

If you only want to redirect a html page, you can at least make the route respond with code 301 by using the [Request Termination Plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-termination/) and set `status_code=301`. You can also return `text/html` mime-type and return

```
<script>location.href = 'https://other-domain.org/new-api/' + location.pathname.replace(/^\/old-api/, '/new-api')</script>
```

in the body to circumvent this restriction.

An alternative would be to implement a Kong Plugin yourself (I don't know about an existing one other than a very rudimentary one, https://github.com/domecloud/kong-plugin-redirect, which might be extended).

PS: I just found [another promising plugin](https://github.com/qnap-dev/kong-plugin-api-transformer) which seems to be more powerful, though I didn't test it yet.